# Reporting stack traces from ADT emulator

Tags: java, android, exception, android-emulator

Does anyone know how to print stack traces for exceptions caught while running in the Android emulator in Eclipse?  I catch the exception and call .printStackTrace() but I cannot find where it is being written.  I have tried .printStackTrace(System.out) and .printStackTrace(System.err). I would be nice to be able to direct them to the Eclipse console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `logcat`. `System.out` and `System.err` are redirected to `logcat` in Android. Just go to `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat` and you'll get all the logged stuff there.

Comment: You may also need to select the emulator from the Devices list in the DDMS perspective, too.